# Non-dimensionalizing the governing Level set equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, surface-tension, viscosity

I have seen in many papers (e.g., *The effect of the dispersed to continuous-phase viscosity ratio on film drainage between interacting drops.* B. Bazhlekov and A.K. Chesters F.N van de Vosse), that during the non-dimensionalization of the two phase flow (for example level set equations) governing equations, the viscosity was made dimensionless by dividing the dispersed phase viscosity by the continues phase. Is it not correct to divide the continues phase viscosity by the dispersed phase viscosity and make it dimensionless?. What is the reason?

Comment: You can do that as well. But, in that case, your dimensionless number would be different from the one defined by the authors.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is not necessary or any rules to divide always by continues fluid viscosity?.

Comment: I do not think that there is any such rule. The dimensionless numbers arising when dividing by continuous phase viscosity may have better physical significance than that of dispersed phase viscosity.